# Big - Oh proof $n^{2^n} = O(2^{2^n})$

Tags: asymptotics

But the book asks me to prove that it's correct:
$$n^{2^n} + 6*2^n = O(2^{2^n})$$
But I think, it's an incorrect one. Because, it's correct only for $n < 2$.

Comment: you prob want to edit the title. and prob a typo, shouldn'tt it be 2 in the first term?

Comment: Oh! You meant "[big O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)"...

Comment: @Lost1 I carefully checked the first term, because it seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=O(g(x))\quad\mbox{ iff }\quad\limsup_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}<\infty$$

But

$$\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{2^n}}{2^{2^n}}=\limsup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{2^n}=\infty$$

Hence $n^{2^n}\neq O(2^{2^n})$